# Qt with SFML errors

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

I try to use Qt with the SFML librairy but I have got some errors compiling my program:

```
C:\AlwaysWithYou\Editeur\sfmlcanvas.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::activate(bool)'
C:\AlwaysWithYou\Editeur\sfmlcanvas.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to sf::RenderWindow::activate(bool)'
moc_qsfmlwidget.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::activate(bool)'
moc_qsfmlwidget.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to sf::RenderWindow::activate(bool)'
collect2.exe:-1: erreur : error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

With this part of the code:

```
#include "sfmlcanvas.h"

SfmlCanvas::SfmlCanvas(QWidget* parent) : QSFMLWidget(parent)
{
}
```

I have already searched for similars problems but I didn't find any answers so please help me! :)

PS: I have compiled SFML by sources with the compiler used by Qt creator (mingw530_32) following this tutorial-> https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Compile-and-Link-SFML-with-Qt-Creator

Ask me if you want some precision!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `sf::RenderWindow::activate` the method is called [setActive](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Window.php#a17ccf8ece0ce0bf2f1e6698bcfa29731).